# Why the smtp server doesn't send emails anymore?

Tags: php, symfony, smtp, symfony-forms

I came across with a very strange problem . i am sending emails through my website to other recipients .its in symfony and i am very much new to this. here is my code

confg.yml

```
swiftmailer:
transport:  smtp
host:       smtp.gmail.com
encryption: ssl
username:   "myusername"
password:   "mypassword"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

here is my form function

```
 public function formemailAction(Request $request)
 {
 // create a task and give it some dummy data for this example
        $newtask = new Task();
        $newtask->setsubject('add subject here');
        $newtask->setdescription("write your feed back here");
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($newtask)
            ->add('subject', 'text')
            ->add('description', 'textarea')
            ->getForm();

 return $this->render('ServiceRequestBundle:Desk:shownotification.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),
 ));
 }
```

in the form on clicking submit i am calling a function in which i am sending an email

```
public function sendemailAction()
  {
      $messages = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
          ->setSubject('again Notification Email')
          ->setFrom('myusername@gmail.com')
          ->setTo('username@gmail.com')
          ->setBody("we know that you dont know whats happening" )
      ;
      $this->get('mailer')->send($messages);

      return $this->render('ServiceRequestBundle:Desk:shownotification.html.twig');
  }
```

now the problem is this it was working fine . but after sending 4 to 5 emails it stops working and my emails are not sending anymore. my first guess was since i am debugging my app again and again and  may be it is happening just because of the same email sending again and again. i follow this [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html)if thats so then how can i solve this problem and if there is any other problem kindly help me .

i check my php error logs and i found this

```
#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Debug\ErrorHandler->handle(2, 'SessionHandler:...', 'C:\xampp\htdocs...', 558, Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\jts\app\cache\dev\classes.php(558): SessionHandler->write('tatrpm617uplo16...', '_sf2_attributes...')
#2 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Proxy\SessionHandlerProxy->write('tatrpm617uplo16...', '_sf2_attributes...')
#3 [internal function]: session_write_close()
#4 {main}
  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\jts\app\cache\dev\classes.php on line
```

Comment: there is an extra backslash in your `sendemailAction()` line 1 before `Swift_Message`. Typo ?

Comment: i tried that but still not working i follow this [tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html)

Comment: try simple PHP codes first. Try `mail()` function to see if SMTP server is working or not.

Comment: ok i sent an email by using simple php **mail()** too and the same problem again. i guess my smtp server stops working. how can i solve this problem now ?

Comment: you probably didn't install a SMTP server. If you are lazy, use Google's mail server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you would need a Relay, since Gmail would think its spam and might block your address.

You can Use PostFix on CentOS or in windows you can install SMTP Server

**CentOS**
http://www.postfix.org/

**WINDOWS:**
you can download SMTP Server

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887

and configure using these steps

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772058(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

In case of smtp transport, check your php logs, there may be issues with the
auth at gmail. Have you tried **tls** instead of **ssl**?

You could try to deliver the mails through your own smtp server:

First you should check if there is an smtp server running on your server:

```
netstat -tulpen | grep :25
```

This should return something similar like this:

```
tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:25  0.0.0.0:* LISTEN  0  8485 1213/master
```

If not you can try to start the server. In case of postfix this is:

```
/etc/init.d/postfix start
```

If you are still getting no mails, check

```
/var/log/maillog
```

It may be that the mails cannot be delivered, you should see more
infos in the maillog

Comment: i am using windows. can you specify the path for windows ??

Comment: On windows it´s much more cumbersome to install a mail server. You should try then to get the smtp gmail working. Try it with tls instead of ssl.